# MySQL Workbench 8.0 quit unexpectedly on MacOS 11.1

Tags: macos, mysql-workbench

I'm taking a database management course next semester, and I would like to get ahead of the game and gain an understanding of SQL. So far, I've downloaded MySQL and was able to access my database using the terminal. I'm having an issue opening MySQL Workbench as it states, "MySQL Workbench quit unexpectedly." I've restarted my OS and re-installed the app to no avail.

Below is the Problem Details and System Configuration

```
Process:               MySQLWorkbench [2942]
Path:                  /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/MySQLWorkbench
Identifier:            com.oracle.workbench.MySQLWorkbench
Version:               8.0.23.CE (1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           MySQLWorkbench [2942]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-01-19 15:31:30.159 -0500
OS Version:            macOS 11.1 (20C69)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        DE32212B-B203-A97E-3794-4A4256956BDF

Sleep/Wake UUID:       FF2D9163-B595-4492-8644-46BB41F52FD3

Time Awake Since Boot: 12000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       2400 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Abort trap: 6
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x6

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff20326792 __abort_with_payload + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff203281d9 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff20328189 abort_with_reason + 19
3   Python3                         0x000000010f4b1f05 fatal_error.cold.1 + 21
4   Python3                         0x000000010f434f78 fatal_error + 536
5   Python3                         0x000000010f43441a Py_InitializeEx + 138
6   libgrt.dylib                    0x000000010bf70422 grt::PythonContextHelper::InitPython() + 16
7   libgrt.dylib                    0x000000010bf7065e grt::PythonContext::PythonContext(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) + 412
8   libgrt.dylib                    0x000000010bf59549 grt::init_python_support(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) + 38
9   libwbpublic.be.dylib            0x000000010c2cc71e bec::GRTManager::init_loaders(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool) + 28
10  libwbpublic.be.dylib            0x000000010c2cc6d4 bec::GRTManager::init_module_loaders(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool) + 102
11  libwbpublic.be.dylib            0x000000010c2cb635 bec::GRTManager::initialize(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) + 55
12  libwbprivate.be.dylib           0x000000010cbe6c55 wb::WBContext::init_(wb::WBFrontendCallbacks*, wb::WBOptions*) + 3517
13  libwbprivate.be.dylib           0x000000010cc124b5 wb::WBContextUI::init(wb::WBFrontendCallbacks*, wb::WBOptions*) + 435
14  com.oracle.workbench.MySQLWorkbench 0x000000010bd5612a -[WBMainController setupBackend] + 1263
15  com.oracle.workbench.MySQLWorkbench 0x000000010bd597b0 -[WBMainController awakeFromNib] + 428
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204264c9 -[NSSet makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 231
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22c2ba48 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 1368
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22c20128 loadNib + 392
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22c1f730 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:options:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 693
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22c1f386 -[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:] + 201
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22c1f164 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 394
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22c11cf8 NSApplicationMain + 566
23  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff20354621 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20335458 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20335458 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20335458 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20335458 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00007fff202a4d84 std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::get() + 70
1   libwbprivate.be.dylib           0x000000010ce8b399 void rapidjson::GenericReader<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>::ParseStringToStream<0u, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::BasicIStreamWrapper<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >, rapidjson::GenericReader<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>::StackStream<char> >(rapidjson::BasicIStreamWrapper<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >&, rapidjson::GenericReader<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>::StackStream<char>&) + 107
2   libwbprivate.be.dylib           0x000000010ce8a19f void rapidjson::GenericReader<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>::ParseString<0u, rapidjson::BasicIStreamWrapper<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >, rapidjson::GenericDocument<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator> >(rapidjson::BasicIStreamWrapper<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >&, rapidjson::GenericDocument<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>&, bool) + 83
3   libwbprivate.be.dylib           0x000000010ce8a327 void rapidjson::GenericReader<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>::ParseObject<0u, rapidjson::BasicIStreamWrapper<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >, rapidjson::GenericDocument<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator> >(rapidjson::BasicIStreamWrapper<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >&, rapidjson::GenericDocument<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>&) + 301
4   libwbprivate.be.dylib           0x000000010ce8a4da void rapidjson::GenericReader<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>::ParseArray<0u, rapidjson::BasicIStreamWrapper<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >, rapidjson::GenericDocument<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator> >(rapidjson::BasicIStreamWrapper<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >&, rapidjson::GenericDocument<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>&) + 178
5   libwbprivate.be.dylib           0x000000010ce8a327 void rapidjson::GenericReader<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>::ParseObject<0u, rapidjson::BasicIStreamWrapper<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >, rapidjson::GenericDocument<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator> >(rapidjson::BasicIStreamWrapper<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >&, rapidjson::GenericDocument<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>&) + 301
6   libwbprivate.be.dylib           0x000000010ce8a4da void rapidjson::GenericReader<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>::ParseArray<0u, rapidjson::BasicIStreamWrapper<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >, rapidjson::GenericDocument<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator> >(rapidjson::BasicIStreamWrapper<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >&, rapidjson::GenericDocument<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>&) + 178
7   libwbprivate.be.dylib           0x000000010ce8a327 void rapidjson::GenericReader<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>::ParseObject<0u, rapidjson::BasicIStreamWrapper<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >, rapidjson::GenericDocument<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator> >(rapidjson::BasicIStreamWrapper<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >&, rapidjson::GenericDocument<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>&) + 301
8   libwbprivate.be.dylib           0x000000010ce89c86 rapidjson::ParseResult rapidjson::GenericReader<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>::Parse<0u, rapidjson::BasicIStreamWrapper<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >, rapidjson::GenericDocument<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator> >(rapidjson::BasicIStreamWrapper<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >&, rapidjson::GenericDocument<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>&) + 80
9   libwbprivate.be.dylib           0x000000010ce89b90 rapidjson::GenericDocument<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>& rapidjson::GenericDocument<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>::ParseStream<0u, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::BasicIStreamWrapper<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > > >(rapidjson::BasicIStreamWrapper<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >&) + 72
10  libwbprivate.be.dylib           0x000000010ce88ffa void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, help::DbSqlEditorContextHelp::DbSqlEditorContextHelp()::$_0> >(void*) + 1165
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20339950 _pthread_start + 224
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2033547b thread_start + 15

Thread 6:: GRTDispatcher
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff203078e2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20339ea2 _pthread_cond_wait + 1305
2   libglib-2.0.0.dylib             0x000000010f2267c1 g_cond_wait_until + 129
3   libglib-2.0.0.dylib             0x000000010f1ac964 g_async_queue_pop_intern_unlocked + 100
4   libglib-2.0.0.dylib             0x000000010f1acafe g_async_queue_timeout_pop + 46
5   libwbpublic.be.dylib            0x000000010c2c08d5 bec::GRTDispatcher::worker_thread(void*) + 455
6   libglib-2.0.0.dylib             0x000000010f2052ba g_thread_proxy + 90
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20339950 _pthread_start + 224
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2033547b thread_start + 15

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000002000209  rbx: 0x0000000000000002  rcx: 0x00007ffee3ebc9d8  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000002  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007ffee3ebca20  rsp: 0x00007ffee3ebc9d8
   r8: 0x00007fd17ae44b40   r9: 0x0000000000000002  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000246
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x0000000000000002
  rip: 0x00007fff20326792  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0x000000010f44bf00
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000209
Trap Number:     133

Thread 0 instruction stream not available.

Thread 0 last branch register state not available.
```

Comment: You need to raise this issue with mysql support! This us like the 5th question today with the exact same issue. If you all talked to mysql support instead of us, they may take the issue more seriously!

Answer (score 2):

MySQL Workbench v8.23 seems to not work for devices running macOS Big Sur 11.1. This may be fixed in the future.

For now, you can get this to work by downloading an older version of workbench. v8.22 worked well for me on Big Sur.

You can find the archive here: https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/

Answer (score 0):

Same proble try to install previous version, for me worked :)